# ¿ Cómo ocultar columna de fechas pasadas en tablas html, y que jquery tome como referencia la columna del día de hoy?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

necesito que me puedan orientar. El título de la pregunta es algo confuso, pero lo explicaré de inmediato.
Tengo una tabla html que contiene 8 columnas:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Apellido</th>
          <th>31-08-2019</th>
          <th>01-09-2019</th>
          <th>02-09-2019</th>
          <th>03-09-2019</th>
          <th>04-09-2019</th>
          <th>05-09-2019</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Gonzalo</td>
          <td>Jeria</td>
          <td>TRABAJO</td>
          <td>TRABAJO</td>
          <td>TRABAJO</td>
          <td>TRABAJO</td>
          <td>TRABAJO</td>
          <td>DESCANSO</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Marcelo</td>
          <td>Reyes</td>
          <td>DESCANSO</td>
          <td>DESCANSO</td>
          <td>DESCANSO</td>
          <td>DESCANSO</td>
          <td>TRABAJO</td>
          <td>TRABAJO</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Julio</td>
          <td>Soto</td>
          <td>VACACIONES</td>
          <td>VACACIONES</td>
          <td>VACACIONES</td>
          <td>VACACIONES</td>
          <td>VACACIONES</td>
          <td>VACACIONES</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</body>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Como puedo utilizar jquery o javascript, para que me oculte las columnas de fechas anteriores(con algún botón), y me resalte la fecha del día de hoy, por ej:(03-09-2019), y que esto se vaya realizando día tras día, para evitar demasiadas columnas. *Me explico*, "que jquery busque la fecha actual día tras día, pero que exista un botón para poder mostrar/ocultar las fechas pasadas."

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas agregar una clase a cada columna para poder ocultarlas.  Te dejo un ejemplo con la primera columna:

```js
$("#ocultar").click(function() {
$('table th').each(function(i, th) {
  var from = th.innerHTML.split("-")
  var f = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0])
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0)
  if (f < today) {
    var clase = $(th).attr('class');
    $("." + clase).hide();
  } else if( f.getTime() === today.getTime()) {
    $(th).addClass('today');
  }  
});
});
```

```css
.today {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Apellido</th>
          <th class="col1">31-08-2019</th>
          <th>01-09-2019</th>
          <th>02-09-2019</th>
          <th>03-09-2019</th>
          <th>04-09-2019</th>
          <th>05-09-2019</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Gonzalo</td>
          <td>Jeria</td>
          <td class="col1">TRABAJO</td>
          <td>TRABAJO</td>
          <td>TRABAJO</td>
          <td>TRABAJO</td>
          <td>TRABAJO</td>
          <td>DESCANSO</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Marcelo</td>
          <td>Reyes</td>
          <td class="col1">DESCANSO</td>
          <td>DESCANSO</td>
          <td>DESCANSO</td>
          <td>DESCANSO</td>
          <td>TRABAJO</td>
          <td>TRABAJO</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Julio</td>
          <td>Soto</td>
          <td class="col1">VACACIONES</td>
          <td>VACACIONES</td>
          <td>VACACIONES</td>
          <td>VACACIONES</td>
          <td>VACACIONES</td>
          <td>VACACIONES</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
<button id="ocultar">Ocultar</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hola alan, gracias por responder.Me sirve lo que hiciste... pero mencioné que me gustaría que exista un botón para mostrar/ocultar las fechas anteriores al 03-09-2019. La verdad  no tengo idea como hacer esto.

Comment: Es super facil, ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Estoy utilizando tu respuesta, y la verdad esta muy buena, ¿Debo ir agregando a cada columna una clase para poder ocultarlas  o Existe la manera automática de ocultar todas las fechas anteriores al día actual, día tras día?

Comment: Podrias agregar la misma clase a todas las fechas que sean menores al dia actual.

Comment: Si, eso es lo que hice.. pero lo que busco es que automáticamente se vayan ocultando las fechas pasadas, respecto al día actual. A modo de ejemplo. **si mañana 04-09-2019,  la tabla debería resaltar ese día, y se mantengan ocultos las fechas anteriores y obviamente el día pasado que sería hoy**

Comment: No se como generas la tabla, pero para agregar la clase necesitas hacerlo en la logica de tu programa.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98247/discussion-between-h6gignacio-and-alanfcm).